# AWS EC2: ssh: connect to host 10.0.0.206 port 22: Connection timed out

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

OS: Ubuntu

public IP from where I try the ssh: 153.5.57.2

**Security rule:**

*Inbound:*

```
Name
    Security group rule ID
    IP version
    Type
    Protocol
    Port range
    Source
    Description
    –   sgr-01a63df5e26bc8e9a   IPv4    HTTP    TCP 80  0.0.0.0/0   –
    –   sgr-0cafa26a9ca34ccbe   IPv4    SSH TCP 22  153.5.57.2/32   –
    –   sgr-047038a9c030dd52b   IPv4    HTTPS   TCP 443 0.0.0.0/0   –
```

*Outbound:*

```
Name
    Security group rule ID
    IP version
    Type
    Protocol
    Port range
    Destination
    Description
    –   sgr-0812dc9c3b21745e1   IPv4    All traffic All All 0.0.0.0/0   –
```

**ACL rule: (Inbound and Outbound)**

```
Rule number
    Type
    Protocol
    Port range
    Source
    Allow/Deny

22  SSH (22)    TCP (6) 22  153.5.57.2/32 Allow

100 All traffic All All 0.0.0.0/0 Allow

\*  All traffic All All 0.0.0.0/0 Deny
```

**Route table:**

```
Destination
    Target
    Status
    Propagated

10.0.0.0/24 local Active    No
```

**Internet Gateway** is attached to my **VPC**.

**Subnet** is attached to my **VPC**.

**Route table** is associated with **subnet**.

**ACL rule** is associated with **subnet**.

```
ssh -vvv -i "my-private-key.pem" ec2-user@10.0.0.206
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.2, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 10.0.0.206 is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to 10.0.0.206 [10.0.0.206] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 10.0.0.206 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host 10.0.0.206 port 22: Connection timed out
```

Comment: what about the security group?

Comment: A time-out is normally an indication that the connection is being blocked by the **Security Group** associated with the instance. Please Edit your Question to show us the **Inbound rules** on the security group. Also, please note that ACLs should not normally be modified unless you have a very specific networking requirement (eg creating a DMZ).

Comment: From where are you attempting to connect to this EC2 instance? Are you connecting from your own computer on the Internet, or from another Amazon EC2 instance? The IP address you have shown is a **private IP address** meaning that it is only valid when used in the same VPC as the instance (not from the Internet).

Comment: @Korgen I updated the security group.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I updated the security group.

Comment: I tried from my windows, it failed so I tried from a linux. I gave the public IP that I took from https://whatismyipaddress.com/.

Comment: Ahhhh, I'm still lost with no way home. Pity for me brothers !

Answer (score 1):

Your security group is permitting access from:

```
SSH TCP 22  153.5.57.2/32
```

Therefore, it appears that you are wanting to connect **from a computer on the Internet** to the Amazon EC2 instance.

However, the command you are using to connect is:

```
ssh -vvv -i "my-private-key.pem" ec2-user@10.0.0.206
```

The IP address of `10.0.0.206` is a [private IP address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) that is **only reachable within the VPC**. It is *not* accessible from the Internet.

To access the EC2 instance from the Internet:

- The instance requires a **Public IP address**
- The instance needs to be in a **Public Subnet** (defined as a subnet that has a Route Table entry to an Internet Gateway)
- You need to specify the public IP address when connecting to the instance